# Outer join with union in Excel 2010 using Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, query, power-query

I've got two tables (two worksheets of the same workbook in Excel 2010):

[image: First table]

[image: Second table]

The result should look like this:

[image]

My SQL code works well:

```
SELECT table_2.ID, table_1.value_1, table_2.value_2 FROM table_1 RIGHT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
UNION
SELECT table_1.ID, table_1.value_1, table_2.value_2 FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Excel with Power Query?

Solved the problem using built-in Microsoft Query and SQL but still interested in a solution using Power Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in Power Query there is an optional parameter for setting the join kind of a Merge Queries (i.e. a [Table.NestedJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260794.aspx) function)

> Table.NestedJoin(table1 as table, key1 as any, table2 as any, key2 as
>   any, newColumnName as text, **optional joinKind as nullable number**) as
>   table

The default value is 1, which is a `LEFT OUTER` join.

And the default GUI for Merge Queries:

[image]

Generates a line in your PQL statement that looks like this:

```
-- LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"ID"},Table1,{"ID"},"NewColumn")
```

Since the joinKind parameter isn't set at all, it defaults to a `LEFT OUTER` join.

If you do check the **Only include matching rows** checkbox, you'll perform an `INNER` join and the generated line looks like this:

```
-- INNER JOIN
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"ID"},Table1,{"ID"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.Inner)
```

(NB: There's a JoinKind enum mapping to the magic numbers of the parameter: so JoinKind.Inner evaluates as 0, JoinKind.LeftOuter as 1, etc.)

In Excel, you have to modify this formula by hand to perform a `FULL OUTER` join:

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"ID"},Table1,{"ID"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.FullOuter)
```

or

```
= Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"ID"},Table1,{"ID"},"NewColumn", 3 )
```

In PowerBI Desktop, there's a dropdown to choose the join kind.